# PHP mail(): Failed to Receive error when sending mulitple emails using own SMTP server

Tags: php, email

I am using our companies `SMTP server` to send email from a PHP script, i have about 10 to 15 emails address that i sent to in a daily basic depending with the systems functionality, now when i tried to add new address and make it until 20 emails then i get the `mail(): Failed to Receive error`, any suggestion how to prevent this? thanks in advance!

For now i am hard coding the email address like below but later i will be storing it on a database.

```
<?php

    $to = "User1@email.com" . ", ";
    $to .= "User2@email.com" . ", ";
    $to .= "User3@email.com" . ", ";
    $to .= "User4@email.com" . ", ";
    $to .= "User5@email.com" . ", ";
    $to .= "User6@email.com" . ", ";
    //...and the list goes on.



       $subject = 'Test Email';
    $message = "
        <html>
        <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
        body, table {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;}
        table td {
        border-bottom-style:solid;
        border-bottom-width:thin;
        border-bottom-color:#CCCCCC;
        border-right-style:solid;
        border-right-width:thin;
        border-right-color:#CCCCCC;}
        .content {
        color:#666666;}
        .maintxt {
        font-size:14px;}
        .sender {
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#0066CC;}
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1 class='maintxt'>Test Email</h1>

        <p>This was sent to test for additional users on proweb email directory</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";


    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: PROWEB' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: userCC1@email.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: userCC2@email.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: userCC3@email.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: userCC4@email.com' . "\r\n";
    //$headers .= "\r\nCc: ryan.malimban@astec-asia.com";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: what shows up on the SMTP server side?

Comment: Ive done some simulation and monitor the SMTP server behavior when i am executing the script and the log is `Timeout connection problem": there have been issues during the message transfer.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a kind of server setting. Did you notice if there is a "fixed" limit? Do it work with just 19 addresses?

Note that as the function [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation states:

> Note:
>   It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient.
>   For the sending of large amounts of email, see the » PEAR::Mail, and » PEAR::Mail_Queue packages.

I don't really think that 20 addresses are too much, but may be it is the right direction to follow.

Anyway I advice to contact the server administrator to ask for any limitation setting.